# How resolve undelivered/unprocced message in akka?

Tags: scala, akka, message, actor

Suppose there are 2 actors: *ClientActor* and *ValidationActor* which are placed in different cluster nodes. *ClientActor* send a messageOne to the *ValidationActor*, *ValidationActor* process a message and send messageTwo to the *ClientActor*. 
How resolve the situation when node with *ValidationActor* fall down and messageOne is not actually delivered? How *ClientActor* may know about this fact?

Comment: The link mentioned in comment in detail explains the strategy you can use in such conditions. Its a very common Issue people new to akka face :)

Comment: It seems that there is no mechnism to ensure that message was delivered. Just wait and throw error by timeout. Also I do not understant how to resolve situations when messagef is not dropped actually, and there is a delay due to server **load not network problems**. Added a comment to answer.